# Passing principal user from one spring boot microservice to other springboot microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, authorization

---

i have two java spring boot microservices .
scheduler microservice and polygonMicroservice.
Before the endpoint is called SpringSecurity is implemented
'''

```
package com.ericsson.dop.polygonmanager.config;

import com.ericsson.edosdp.dop.commons.config.ProdProfileCondition;
import com.ericsson.edosdp.dop.commons.config.SessionConfig;
import com.ericsson.edosdp.dop.commons.config.access.AccessService;
import com.ericsson.edosdp.dop.commons.config.access.CustomerOnlyRoleSuffixAccessService;
import com.ericsson.edosdp.dop.commons.config.access.MethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;

/**
 * Configures HTTP access for prod profile.
 */
@Configuration
@Conditional(ProdProfileCondition.class)
@Import({MethodSecurityConfiguration.class, SessionConfig.class})
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Allowed security roles.
     */
    private String[] securityRoles;

    private String[] modulePrefix;

    @Value("${manager.security.authorization.roles}")
    public void setSecurityRoles(String[] securityRoles) {
        this.securityRoles = securityRoles.clone();
    }

    @Value("${manager.security.authorization.prefix}")
    public void setModulePrefix(String[] modulePrefix) {
        this.modulePrefix = modulePrefix;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessService accessService() {
        return new CustomerOnlyRoleSuffixAccessService(modulePrefix);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority(securityRoles)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

//

```
public class CustomerOnlyRoleSuffixAccessService extends RoleSuffixAccessService {
    private static final String UNDERSCORE = "_";
    private static final String AGNOSTIC_FLAVOR = "AGNOSTIC";
    private static final String AGNOSTIC_SUFFIX = UNDERSCORE + AGNOSTIC_FLAVOR + ENGINEER_SUFFIX;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerOnlyRoleSuffixAccessService.class);

    public CustomerOnlyRoleSuffixAccessService(String[] modulePrefix) {
        super(modulePrefix);
    }

    public CustomerOnlyRoleSuffixAccessService() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomerOnlyRoleSuffixAccessService(String[] modulePrefix, String rolePrefixPattern) {
        super(modulePrefix, rolePrefixPattern);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean check(Principal user, String customer, String[] modulePrefix, String vendor, String technology) {
        LOGGER.debug(String.format("Checking access for customer [%s] for user [%s]...", customer, user.getName()));

        if (customer == null) {
            // for cases where customer comes from an empty filter.
            return false;
        }

        List<RoleBean> roles = getRoleBeans(user);
        if (roles.contains(ROLE_ADMIN_BEAN)) {
            // Access granted for admin role.
            LOGGER.debug("Access granted!");
            return true;
        }

        // Only customer is taken into account when building roles.
        // Example: ROLE_NDOSW_DEV_VDT_ATT_ENGINEER
        Set<RoleBean> expectedRoles = Arrays.stream(modulePrefix).map(prefix -> new RoleBean(prefix + customer.toUpperCase() + AGNOSTIC_SUFFIX)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<RoleBean> agnosticRoles = roles.stream().peek(role -> role.setFlavor(AGNOSTIC_FLAVOR)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        // Access is granted for the expected roles or admin role
        boolean accessGranted = !CollectionUtils.intersection(agnosticRoles, expectedRoles).isEmpty();
        LOGGER.debug(accessGranted ? "Access granted!" : "Permission denied!");

        return accessGranted;
    }

}
```

polygonmicroservice has an end point like this

```
@PostMapping(path = "/update", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public long batchUpdate(@RequestBody List<PolygonInfoDto> polygonsUpdates,
                            Principal user) throws PolygonManagerException {       
        return service.safeBatchUpdate(user,service.listAllById(polygonsUpdates.stream().map(PolygonInfoDto::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())), polygonsUpdates);
        }
```

now from a scheduler microservice I have to call the above endpoint.
generally it accepts the sessionid but in case of schedular i am not able to pass the required information to access the endpoint
how can I pass the principal user and authorities information from scheduler microservice to polygon microservice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using exchange method from RestTemplate class in your service:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          ResponseEntity<String> result = 
            restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
          return result.getBody().toString();
```

Comment: Hello Rehan I need to pass user authorities also with the credentials how can i pass that information to the restTempalte exchange()

Comment: Hi, you can add it in the RequestBody (entity)

Comment: Thank you for your response i have edited my question with more details please guide i am just stuck.